# Defaulted to wrong color scheme, how do I change it back?

Tags: unity, 11.10, window, colors

I understand that there's no (easy) way tot change the color scheme in Oneiric, and that would really be fine if it defaulted to the right one in the first place.  Instead, it defaulted to the theme I was using when I upgraded to Natty, and now I can't change it for the life of me.  See the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any possible way I can get the colors to look right?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)